# Trying to find voltage v across resistor

Tags: thevenin, homework, superposition

[image: schematic image for question]

I can find the equivalent Thevenin resistance, but am unsure where to assume ground/how to do nodal analysis (what is the rule) when the current source is passing through the voltage source.

When I do superposition, I find the Rt to be (1/(5+15)+1/5)^-1 + 10 Rt=14. Is it correct to assume then the I=20/14=1.43 then do voltage divider with the current source as an open circuit?

Comment: Use superposition.

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here. You will need to put forth a significant effort and show us **all** of your work. Then, ask a specific question. In this case, you need to find the open-circuit output voltage, using whatever circuit analysis techniques you like. Can you do that?

Comment: Check your class notes, you will probably find you did not define the question properly and made some inaccurate assumptions.